# Automatically check related groups when main group is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am to make a script that makes it possible to select groups during an create-action. The structure of my group table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rand_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentID` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
  `deleted` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DBdate` int(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

If the group is a main-group, parentID will be set to 0. If the group is a sub group, the parentID will be set to the main group's id (naturally).

The design is temporarily and looks like this:
![Checkboxes][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbnwO.png

---

The HTML-code is as follows:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox">Group 1<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox">Sub group 1<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox">Sub sub group 3<br>
    <input type="checkbox">Group 2<br>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox">Sub group 2<br>
</div>
```

My question is: how can I make a script that makes it possible to check the sub-groups when a main groups i checked? Do you perhaps have a link you could show?

Comment: Could you please omit the PHP and SQL and just give us the HTML..? This is tagged as a JavaScript question

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. Here you go

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$('input:first-child').on('click',function(){
  $('input:not(:first-child)').attr('checked',true)
})
```

This would work better if you added some ID's to your buttons. As it is written now, it could have unexpected effects if there are other input elements anywhere on the page.